# Conversion of hexadecimal string constant to decimal value using C

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

The following program gives the result as `0` instead of the expected decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal string constant.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_htoi(char[]);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", my_htoi("0xABC"));
    return 0;
}

int my_htoi(char str[]) {
    int i, num = 0;
    for (i = 0; i != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i+1] == 'x' || str[i+1] == 'X') {
            i = i + 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - '0');
        } else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'f') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - 'a' + 10);
        } else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'F') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - 'A' + 10);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

While the following program runs fine and outputs the correct decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal string constant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_htoi(char[]);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", my_htoi("0xABC"));
    return 0;
}

int my_htoi(char str[]) {
    int i, num = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        if (str[i+1] == 'x' || str[i+1] == 'X') {
            i = i + 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - '0');
        } else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'f') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - 'a' + 10);
        } else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'F') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - 'A' + 10);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

The only difference is in the way we find the qualifying condition for the loop. Why does it not work with the null byte checking?

Comment: You are comparing the *index* `i` to zero, which does not make sense. You should compare `str[i]` to it instead.

Comment: Another note is that `i=i+1` if the encountered char is 'x' or 'X' is an error. When `continue` is executed the `for` executes the increment of the `i` variable, then your code, when 'x' is encounterd, skips the first char after 'x'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- the loop index `i` is compared to `'\0'` instead of `str[i]`, causing immediate termination of the loop with a return value of `0`.
- the test for `x` is incorrect: it would cause `"1x2"` to convert to `2` instead of `1`.
- you accept letters beyond `f` and convert them to digits. The function should instead stop parsing at the first character that is not a hex digit.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_htoi(const char[]);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", my_htoi("0xABC"));
    return 0;
}

int my_htoi(const char str[]) {
    int i = 0, num = 0;
    if (str[0] == '0' && (str[1] == 'x' || str[1] == 'X'))
        i += 2;
    for (; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - '0');
        } else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'f') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - 'a' + 10);
        } else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'F') {
            num = num * 16 + (str[i] - 'A' + 10);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong code: `i != '\0'` checks if the *index* is 0.

```
for(i = 0; i != '\0'; ++i) {
```

Should be the below to check if the *element* `str[i]` is the *null character*.

```
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
```

---

Other issues exists [unneeded increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049588/conversion-of-hexadecimal-string-constant-to-decimal-value-using-c/55050653#comment96850849_55049588), `int` overflow (better to use `unsigned` here), wrong `x` detection - consider "0x0x0x1", leading `-` or `+`, `char str[]` --> `const char str[]`, ...